# Order By Rand() with Where clause

Tags: mysql, random

I need a faster alternative for

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE cat='catname' 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 2):

If the table is very big, shuffling inside your application could be very slow.

What about this solution:

Find out the size of the table (how many rows). than, programmatically find 6 random numbers between 0 and `number_of_rows`.

The second query for searching the rows:

```
select * from table where id = id1 or id = id2...
```

Comment: I think this is the right idea, though you would need to do this in a transaction or the size of the db might grow between count query and the select

Answer (score 0):

The faster way is don't use `RAND()` in your query. Shuffle your results inside your application.

Comment: For example, he has 500k rows, select them all and then shuffle in the app? :)

Comment: Exactly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592751/why-dont-use-mysql-order-by-rand

Comment: The database can do this much faster than any in memory code can do it. So, this does not seem to be a faster alternative for the query.

Comment: @Briedis : any way he has to select all 500k from DB

Comment: @Baszz - How can you prove it? The query without rand IS a faster alternative to the query and great relief to the database in most cases (mysql won't use cache for rand queries). It may or may be not to the application in general - this should be debugged in application but it is the simplest and easiest to implement alternative to check in the first place.

Comment: Just made some quick tests with 1k record table, one with ORDER BY RAND other with PHP shuffle - avg. request speed for first one was 0.85s, for the 2nd one 0.6s.