# Randomizing database results using php instead of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, random, ezsql

I currently use EZSQL class in php to query the MySQL database. I am trying to grab random records from the database, but I would like to know if I could randomize the results via php instead of the sql query itself. The query currently looks like this:

```
$results = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND()");

foreach($results AS $result)
{

//code here

}
```

Instead could I just grab the results from the db then randomize it via php? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  The randomization is probably faster in the database.

Comment: If there will be a `LIMIT` involved, you will go back to SQL's `RAND()`, which works just fine. If you think `RAND()` is a problem for large databases (not true) then you will have to use a `LIMIT` to not select billions of rows. So there you have it: `ORDER BY RAND()` is your only choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDER BY RAND() is not recommended: [Why don't use mysql ORDER BY RAND()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592751/why-dont-use-mysql-order-by-rand)

Also: 
http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

You can just call `shuffle($results)` to randomize an array

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @shuffle, but if you really want to use PHP I wouldn't use foreach; Instead, take $results size, get random number between 0 and length-1, and use it get n-th element from array