# Random row from set of results

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know if it is possible to retrive one single random row from search results. I mean I have query like this:

```
SELECT mp.name,mp.icon,mp.id,mp.wspx,mp.wspy,ms.icon FROM maps_points as mp JOIN maps_section as ms ON(ms.id = mp.section)
```

I would like to get one random row from results generated from this query. Is that possible with one mysql query or should I just get all results and get this one random in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

a simple way is to add `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` to the query. Do take a look at some of the reasons why this can be a bad idea though, e.g.

- [Why don't use mysql ORDER BY RAND()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592751/why-dont-use-mysql-order-by-rand)
- [MySQL: Alternatives to ORDER BY RAND()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand)
- [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT mp.name,mp.icon,mp.id,mp.wspx,mp.wspy,ms.icon 
 FROM maps_points as mp 
 JOIN maps_section as ms ON(ms.id = mp.section) 
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I knew this one, but is there better and faster way to do that ? I mean I've seen some other approaches but they were all about random row from table and I need to pick random row from some set of results :)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - please note that this isn't a forum, and you should only post answers which are actually answers. Comment on individual answers instead.